# print_r showing empty results from POST

Tags: php

Why is `$email` and `$pass` not printing out, they are posting as empty. 
I'm getting the following results from `print_r()`

```
    [email] => 
    [password] =>
```

Below is my code. What am i doing wrong

```
<?php
$email = $_POST["data[User][email]"];
$pass = $_POST["data[User][password]"];
$base = 'https://api.whatever.com/Api?';

$params = array(
    'Format' => 'json'
    ,'email' => "$email"
    ,'password' => "$pass"

);

$url = $base . http_build_query( $params );
$result = file_get_contents( $url );

echo '<pre>';
print_r( json_decode( $result ) );
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Comment: And what does `var_dump($_POST)` give you?

Comment: @deceze I do see `$email` and `$pass` with `print_($_POST)`. Why can't i see it with `json_decode($result)`

Comment: Show us the exact data you see from `var_dump($_POST)`. `$_POST["data[User][email]"]` is probably obviously wrong.

Comment: @deceze This is what i see from var_dump `<pre>array(2) {
  ["_method"]=>
  string(4) "POST"
  ["data"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["User"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["email"]=>
      string(14) "asdasd@asd.com"
      ["password"]=>
      string(6) "asdasd"
    }
  }
}
</pre>`. The input field looks like `<input name="data[User][email]">`

Comment: You should use `$_POST["data"]["User"]["email"]` to get the value, not `$_POST["date[User][email]"]`.

Comment: @passerby. Awesome. That works. If you can post it as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: you must be missing form element names in html form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extending from comment:

If you post something like

```
<input name="data[User][email]" value="test@test.com" />
```

You'll have to use

```
$_POST["data"]["User"]["email"]
```

to retrieve corresponding value.